# dplyr::do() requires named function?

Tags: r, dplyr

The following works fine:

```
library(dplyr) 
m <- function(df) {
  mod <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = df)
  pred <- predict(mod,newdata = df["Sepal.Width"])
  data.frame(df,pred)
}
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(m(.))
```

I thought that this would work if I used an anonymous function, but it does not:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(function(df) {
    mod <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = df)
    pred <- predict(mod,newdata = df["Sepal.Width"])
    data.frame(df,pred)
  })
Error: Results are not data frames at positions: 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need an anonymous function:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do({
    mod <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .)
    pred <- predict(mod, newdata = .["Sepal.Width"])
    data.frame(., pred)
  })
```

Comment: As fun as the other answer was, this answer is much cleaner!  I keep forgetting that `.` can be a pronoun for the entire dataset.

Answer (score 13):

You can't get rid of the `.`.

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do((function(df) {
    mod <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = df)
    pred <- predict(mod,newdata = df["Sepal.Width"])
    data.frame(df,pred)
  })(.))
```

That will work.  The `.` is necessary.  The `.` is love.  Keep the `.`.

Comment: I love this answer so much! I had tried that, but i'd forgotten to wrap the function in () first :$

Comment: could you explain what's going on here? Why is the function in ()?And why is the dot needed? And why is the dot in ()?

Comment: It is absolutely not clear what is going on here from a syntax point of view...

Comment: The function is in parentheses because it is being created anonymously and then called with the alias of `.` as the argument. Wrapping the anonymous function definition in parentheses is necessary because then it gets returned as an object to be called. Remove the parentheses and you have a syntax error.