# R lm on each factor level

Tags: r, apply, lm, factors

I'm hoping to find some guidance on both the how-to-code level and on the how-to-solve level in R.  I have a simple data frame as follows:

```
str(pf)
   'data.frame':  1536 obs of 4 variables:
   $ dt : POSIXct 
   $ pfRet : num 
   $ Src : Factor w/6 Levels "ALPA" , "OMEGA", "GAMMA" , ..
   $ ret : num
```

I simply want to see lm(pfRet ~ ret ) for each of the 6 different factors and compare them.  I would love to be able to get to an output showing sorted by the p value for the lm for each factor level.  I am trying to ask the question, for each factor ( ALPHA, OMEGA, GAMA, et al), which one best explains the relationship between pfRet and ret?

From a programming perspective there's probably a way to get a vector of the 6 factor levels and then apply lm over the frame.  But I couldn't get it to work right.  I tried something along the lines of:

```
GenLm = function(x) { 
  y=pf[which[(pf$Src==x,)]
  return(lm(y$pfRet ~ y$ret )) }

testList = data.frame( Src = as.character(unique( pf$Src ) ) )

testList$lm = apply(  ... ?? )
```

I tried various combinations of apply, ddply, etc.  I just couldn't get it into an easy format where an output could be generated showing the fits for each variable.

Thanks, Josh
From a higher level perspective, is this the right way to go about it?  This is something surely that R users deal with all of the time.

Comment: See e.g. `nlme::lmList`

Comment: also see results of using `dplyr`, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376765/dplyrdo-requires-named-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lmList`, in `nlme` or `lme4` packages, will do this out of the box (they're basically equivalent, except that the `lme4` one can handle GLMs as well as linear models, but might be *slightly* less robust in some cases)

For example:

```
library("lme4")
mm <- lmList(Reaction~Days|Subject,sleepstudy)
summary(mm)
```

Comment: Guys, thanks so much.  That is very helpful.  On the how-to-program it front that answers it.

Comment: Ty.  On the conceptual side, is the right way is just to dcast the data and do a multiple regression?  If you have two factors and they are pretty close to each-other would it give a partial wt on two of the independent vars?   eg, if you were regressing `taxi.fare~miles.traveled+car.time`, let's say that miles traveled was the best fit in terms of residual error and p value. But time.in.car would probably be close.  So what's the right approach?  Would a multiple regression be the right way to do this?  Or should I do it the way that I was, with separate regressions on each variable?