# Predict() in wider range

Tags: r, dplyr, nls

I am sorry to repeat this question over and over but it seems that I have poor understanding in predicting wider range. It seems that if the data's nrow matches well with predicting values you have no error. However, if you want to predict for ***different range*** we will be getting an error.

Using the same data from [dplyrdo-requires-named-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376765/dplyrdo-requires-named-function?noredirect=1&lq=1)

it works well. But if you want to change the range of the fitting I am getting an error!

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do({
    mod <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .)
    pred <- predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(Sepal.Width=seq(1,10,length.out=51)))
    data.frame(., pred)
  })
```

**Error in data.frame(., pred) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 50, 51**

I understand that the new range does not match with the previous data `.`.
OTH, I need to predict for wider range of `Sepal.Width` values. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `data.frame(.,pred)` you're trying to bind together an existing data frame with 50 rows and a new prediction with 51 rows.  If you replace this line by `data.frame(pred)` everything works fine:

```
# A tibble: 153 x 2
# Groups:   Species [3]
   Species     pred
    <fctr>    <dbl>
 1  setosa 3.329491
 2  setosa 3.453779
 3  setosa 3.578067
 ...
```

Comment: That's cool but if you want to plot something with using the same `.` data.frame it is useful to have `data.frame(.,pred)`.In other case I guess we need to build another data from this. For instance, if I wanted to plot `Sepal.Length_predicted` vs `pred` I need to build new `data.frame`. Am I correct?

Comment: and this `Sepal.Lenght_predicted` is coming from whatever the fitting coef's that we get from `lm`.